# do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com should reply to mails with a "This mailbox is not monitored"

Tags: feature-request, jobs, email

An appreciative user of the Careers 2.0 service, I've failed a user design hurdle that I feel could be improved. Email interactions on the service are being sent to my Gmail account. I responded in-service to a compelling proposal from an employer. The next mail was from the HR team proposing dates for a follow-up. This, I mistakenly replied to from my Gmail account directly. A day passed and, when no reply arrived, I realized I'd replied to the do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com account which was suitably masked by Gmail's auto-naming feature.

**Proposal**: send automated responses to messages sent to the do-not-reply account pointing out the mailer's mistake (okay, I'll accept stupidity but I'll provide no apologies for being imperfect ;-)).

**Update**: I sent a mail directly to the DNR account from my Gmail account and have/did not receive a reply from it. The way Gmail presents the mails that I'm receiving, it curtails the mail with elipsis which, if I were to expand (I rarely do particularly in-thread) would have shown me the "reply to this message" guidance and link.

Comment: Alternatively, send out mails with a `Reply-To` header.

Comment: Generally when you email a Do Not Reply email address, the mailing server on their end *rejects* the email which causes it to bounce back, in which case your mail client should notify you of the failed message. Does SE not do this? This has always been my experience when I send emails to DNR addresses on Yahoo Mail.

Comment: I guess mine too but I'm reasonably certain that it didn't happen in this case. if it had, I would have realized my mistake and sent the mail from the StackOverflow Careers app. I checked my Gmail junk folder and the reply's not there either.

Comment: TRiG - Yes, that would be ideal but then these escape StackOverflow's walled garden (I don't have a problem with that but evidently SOees do)